# Cannot install MySQL 8 on Disco Dingo

Tags: mysql, 19.04

I have upgraded to Disco Dingo, but right now I can't install MySQL 8 as it's not available from the official MySQL repository.

Is there any alternative repository or PPA from which I could install MySQL 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can download MySQL binaries from the [MySQL download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).

Here is a screenshot of selecting Ubuntu 19.04 for MySQL Community Server 8.0.16:

[image: MySQL Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo]